# Authentication using custom User wtih Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Tags: spring, web-services, authentication

I am trying to implement web services authentication. I planned to use Wss4jSecurityInterceptor for authentication, encryption and signingss soap message. The current web application is depending on 3 attributes to authenticate (username, password, customer zone id). customer zone id is used in authentication because the username can be same across multiple zones. The web application just validated posted user name, password and zone id against database values. The Username Token is providing only two attributes. I want to know whether, is it possible to pass additional attribute (zone id) with this interceptor and authenticate the user. If yes, can you please provide the sample code.

I am using spring 3, Spring web services 2.1.4.

Comment: you cannot add attributes to the token. you can add your zone id in your soap header and do your authentication.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the approach. I will do authentication by using my own interceptor and will use Wss4jSecurityInterceptor for digital signature and encryption & decryption